# How do I run a Java application multiple times concurrently?

Tags: java, multithreading

Java class snippet :

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException SQLException, ParseException {
    TaskCheck tc = new TaskCheck();

    if (args.length != 1)
    {
      System.err.println("Missing parameter. Please pass the task Name.");
      System.exit(1);
    }

    else
    {
      // Logic goes here
    }
}
```

I run the above Java class with an argument. For ex:

```
java TaskCheck "testtask1"
```

I will need to run this Java class concurrently with different arguments. So, should I be using multi-threading to achieve this?

For Ex:

```
java TaskCheck "testtask1"

java TaskCheck "testtask2"

java TaskCheck "testtask3"
```

Comment: You do not run classes.  You execute methods.

Comment: @user5001305 : Share what you have attempted so far.

Comment: I have tried cron job scheduler and autosys job. but it doest work efficiently for this work, That is why i am looking for an idea here

Comment: What doesnt work? Can you explain

Comment: Made your title into a question to fit the guidelines written in [how to ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually it has nothing to do with multi-threading.  You just want to run your program multiple times concurrently.  It is normally achieved by your OS.

For example, under Unix, you can do

```
#> java TaskCheck "testtask1" &
#> java TaskCheck "testtask2" &
#> java TaskCheck "testtask3" &
```

Under Windows,

```
#> start java TaskCheck "testtask1"
#> start java TaskCheck "testtask2"
#> start java TaskCheck "testtask3"
```

If you want a pure Java solution, you can look into `Runtime.exec()` and `ProcessBuilder` to create child processes by running the `java` command.

Comment: Thank you! I will check this out. I was actually thinking the same way. But can't decide how do i want to pass the argument concurrently. Will try it out.

Answer (score 0):

Multithreading is one way to achieve parallelism

```
public class Echo{

    public static void main(final String[] args){
        if (args.length == 0)
        {
            System.err.println("Missing parameter. Please pass the task Name.");
            System.exit(1);
        }

        for(final String taskName : args){
            Thread t = new Thread(){
                public void run(){
                    System.out.println(taskName);
                    TaskCheck tc = new TaskCheck();

                }
            };
            t.start();
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the responses. I will try these options.

Comment: Hi I updated my original post. Can you please take a look at that?